# If $x+1$ is a factor of $ax^4 + bx^2 + c,$ what is the value of $a + b + c?$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, factoring

The same question was posed here [Find the value of a+b+c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696646/find-the-value-of-abc) but I cannot make sense of the answer.

My long division must be incorrect as I ended up with $a+b+c$ which is definitely wrong. I added $0$ to represent $x^3$ and $x^1$ terms.

I know the remainder should be zero if $x+1$ is a factor.

I am not putting two and two together.

Comment: If $x+1$ is a factor then $x=-1$ is a root. @user554754 can you finish?

Comment: You have to put $ signs around your MathJax for it to be formatted.

Comment: In fact, if a definite answer exists, only one answer i spossible

Comment: Your result is $ax^4+bx^2+c=(\cdots)\cdot(x+1)+\color{red}{a+b+c}$ and you know that it should be $ax^4+bx^2+c=(\cdots)\cdot(x+1)+\color{red}{0}$ and the question asks for the value of $a+b+c$. The rest is really like puting two and two together

Comment: I added a few details to the linked question.

Comment: `My long division must be incorrect as I ended up with $a+b+c\;$ **which is definitely wrong**` Why wrong? That *is* in fact the correct remainder:

$$
\begin{align}
ax^4 + bx^2 + c &= ax^3(x \color{red}{+1}) \color{red}{- ax^3} + bx^2 + c \\
 &= ax^3(x+1) -ax^2(x\color{red}{+1}) \color{red}{+ax^2} + bx^2 + c \\
 &= (ax^3-ax^2)(x+1)+(a+b)x(x\color{red}{+1}) \color{red}{-(a+b)x}+c \\
 &= \big(ax^3-ax^2+(a+b)x\big)(x+1) -(a+b)(x\color{red}{+1})\color{red}{+a+b}+c \\
 &= \big(ax^3-ax^2+(a+b)x-(a+b)\big)(x+1) + \boxed{a+b+c}
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: Oh wow I misread the question. So its asking for the overall value of a+b+c which is equal to zero? I thought I had to find the value of a, b, and c which seems impossible with no coefficient.

Answer (score 4):

$x = -1$ is a root of polynomial
put $x = -1$ in $a x^4 + b x^2 + c$
$a + b + c = 0$